# pages repeating while creating a report in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, report, rdlc

Im trying to create a report template via .rdlc file, but no matter how I style this file in designer I always get as a result printed last page of the document with the content of the second last page.

Any ideas how to change it?

Or is there any best practice how to style those .rdlc report tempaltes?

Comment: I didnt get it can you show a screenshot

Comment: screenshot of the .xps file? I dont think that it would be useful, what do you need it for?